# how to use images in css with height and width in percentage

Tags: html, css

[image]   **Html**

```
 <li ><a id="restaurant" href="/restaurant.htm"></a></li>
```

here am placeing one image with id=restaurant, it works fine here my problem is when i using media tag in css for mobile or table the size should be % then how can i use the css for mobile and tablet ?? actuvally image size was height=560 width=280, we should show one half an image height when hover another half will show .

one more point how to give image width as 100% for mobiles ,is negative values are works in percentage???

**css**

```
#restaurant
    {display: block;
      width: 280px;
      height: 278px;
      background: url(../images/page/restaurantMarketing1.jpg)  no-repeat;}

    #restaurant:hover
    {background-position: 0 -278px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the image as a background, use [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property to set it's size.

Something lie

```
#restaurant
{
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  height: 278px;
  background: url(../images/page/restaurantMarketing1.jpg)  no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
}
#restaurant:hover
{
 background-position: 0 -278px;
 background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: image show full size image when hover only it shows correctly

Comment: ADded one image can it understand what am trying to say

Comment: can't you achieve this using `background-position`..?

Answer (score 0):

```
#restaurant
{display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: url(../images/page/restaurantMarketing1.jpg)  no-repeat;}
```

just put percentage instead of pixels.

or place it like this:

```
<li>
<a id="restaurant" href="/restaurant.html">
<img src="./images/page/restaurantMarketing1.jpg" id="restaurant-img"/>
</a>
</li>
```

That way you can manipulate the image as u want

Answer (score 0):

Try the    `img` tag with max-width 100%:

`<li ><a id="restaurant" href="/restaurant.htm"><img src="../images/page/restaurantMarketing1.jpg" style="width:560px;height:280px;max-width:100%;"></a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

if you got a lot mobile specific styles, try use media query to do responsive design
the way will like:

```
/*this is only apply when screen width is less than or equal 768px
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px){
 #restaurant{
   width:100%;/*or whatever you want*/
 }
}
```

for more information about media queries, [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

otherwise, just use max-width will work.